# Cordova application Android compatibility

Tags: android, cordova, compatibility

I just published my application on Google play. My config sets min and target Android versions:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="31" />
```

It doesn`t set android-maxSdkVersion as suggested. Alghout this, the application is not available for Android 13 devices. This screenshot comes from Google Play:

[image]

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your issue was, but for the record, you do not need to use targetSDK=32, you should be able to build and upload to google play with targetSDK 31 (I have uploaded apps to the store with targetSDK 31 earlier this month).
My guess would be that just having build tools for api-level 33 solved your issue. Also kinda makes sense that you need to have the build tools for the android version you want your app to be available on.

Answer (score -1):

So, finally I found the solution - it is necessary to install SDK 33 under Android studio, update Java to version 11 and set target SDK to at least 32. Once I did this, the automatic max version was removed from Google Play.